# Linux: "fstab" with additional mount options?

Tags: linux, mount, glusterfs, fstab

I'm using "GlusterFS" Client, to mount the GlusterFS Volume on my Web Server. Below is the MOUNT command when I manually mount from the command line:

```
# mount -t glusterfs -o aux-gfid-mount gluster1:/gv0 /var/www/html
```

I don't know how to put that `-o aux-gfid-mount` option inside the `/etc/fstab`. So my `fstab` is still, lacking that option:

```
gluster1:/gv0 /var/www/html/ glusterfs defaults,_netdev,fetch-attempts=5 0 0
```

How do I put that `-o aux-gfid-mount` option inside the `fstab` please?

Comment: This isn't a programming question, and so is off-topic on SO.   That said, the fourth field in fstab has the options, delimited by commas.  So add your option to that.   See `man fstab` for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment:

```
gluster1:/gv0 /var/www/html/ glusterfs defaults,_netdev,aux-gfid-mount,fetch-attempts=5 0 0
```